# Load thumbnail image into PictureBox from directory

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I use the following code to get thumbnail of image in Resources, and display on Picturebox.

```
Image tmp = (System.Drawing.Image)myManager.GetObject(tempImage);
                cfgPassPicture[m].Image = tmp.GetThumbnailImage(40, 40, new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback), System.IntPtr.Zero);
```

How do I do this for images in directory (instead of resources), given only the URL?
I can load image into PictureBox via ImageLocation property, but not sure how to use Image property of PictureBox for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
  myPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile("yourimagepath.jpg");
```